# Tracking an event within another event

Tags: user-interface, mfc, wxwidgets

I am wondering if the following is possible to achieve, if so what is a good way to start with:

I have a wxGrid which have the events, among the others, OnGridCmdEditorShown and the wxMouseEvent OnLeftDown. When I start editing a cell, the OnGridCmdEditorShown is fired up until either I press enter or click on another cell. However, what I want to do is when I am still editing the cell (in the OnGridCmdEditorShown event) I want to get clicks from OnLeftDown. In another words, OnLeftDown should not terminate OnGridCmdEditorShown event. To give you a clearer view you can think of what MS Excel is doing when entering a formula: we are editing a cell while we can still click on different cells.

I might be wrong but overall, I guess, my question is how I can control another event within an event, such as controlling OnLeftDown within OnGridCmdEditorShown. I thought maybe firing up a thread or having an event loop within the OnGridCmdEditorShown could be a good idea but I am not very familiar with either.

Any ideas with a simple example code will be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility to do what you want with the existing `wxGrid` that I see is to define a custom editor control that captures the mouse while it's active. I didn't actually try doing this, but I think it should work.

I do wonder how are you going to allow the user to cancel editing using the mouse if you do this...

Comment: I actually tried the similar idea such as redirecting events of mouse click to GridCellChange by `Connect(wxEVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK,wxGridEventHandler(mygrid::OnGridCellChange), NULL, this);`. Since I can not reroute the wxKeyEvent to the grid events, handling key events is becoming a problem as well as rerouting the mouseclick to its original state.

Instead I will try subclassing `wxGridCellEditor` and then setting the editor of the edited cell to the new one. Not sure if this will work but seems like there is a hope.